# Get current date past midnight, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the current date, even if the time has passed midnight. Imagine it's friday night the 6th of June 2014 - we check the date Saturday at 2 am, but we still want this to count as being friday. How would I go about this?

Let's just say we cut it at 9am the next day. I.e. we will assume previous date until the time has passed 9 am. Yes, this is software used at a nightclub, as you can imagine.

I guess this would involve something like subtracting 1 day from the current date if the hour is less than 10?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Clearly 2 am on the 7th of June is not the 6th of June

Comment: As I described, this is for a nightclub. Usually they don't consider midnight the point where the date changes, as they usually open before midnight but are also open past midnight and the next evening, which would cause the numbers to get messed up if you switch dates at midnight.

Comment: To be honest, if this is an app for their customers I think it would just confuse them as they would already being acting stupid through the consumption of alcohol however I can see a business reasoning behind it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but let me elaborate: The app runs on iPad and is used to register what type of guest (member, free, regular) etc. enters and by that also how many. Let's assume we start counting at 11 pm when the club opens and we let in 300 people in an hour. Then the clock strikes midnight and we want to still count as though it's Friday, not Saturday, 'cause we're also open on Saturday and don't want to mix those who enter at 11pm on Saturday with those who enter after midnight on Friday. You follow?

Comment: Yeah I follow but that just makes me think why do you need to do it again, the business reason why I was thinking was because it was for customers and you could confuse them but I don't see why you need to do what your planning if it's not for customers. But it's your app so it's up to you.

Comment: The guy at the door is probably hammered himself and is not to be concerned with what date it is, midnight or not. All he has to do is press buttons and the registrations must land on the right date, no matter what time it is. I don't understand your concerns? And no, this is not for AppStore and is specific to this club only.

Comment: If I don't shift the date it's going to be one big mess for sure.

Comment: Not that this has anything to with the app but really the guy (Your security) at the door is hammered himself? That would just discourage me from coming to you club, but that's a different matter. As for the app I would say the way you are thinking of doing it will work but in my opinion it is a messy why of doing it. I would just take the current date of when you start and then every time he presses the button it just adds to a count, that seems a lot simpler

Comment: Security and pickers is not the same kind of personnel, also I was mainly kidding to illustrate a point.

How in the world is it simpler to seperate the evening into two dates by midnight when they want the numbers for that date and that date only, midnight or not? Then you have to post-process all the results and add timestamps to see which are before and after midnight?

Comment: OK, yes, I see you could do that. But what happens when the app crashes for whatever reason, the iPad runs out of power and you have to restart? Then you have to tell it what date it is instead of it just figuring it that out on its own by subtracting 9 hours - that will ALWAYS yield the correct date in any thinkable situation.

Comment: How do you think you're going to remember how many people have already entered if it crashes, your just going to start up again and start at zero. Like I say this is your app do it the way you think is best but I wouldn't do it this way, it just seems over complicated for something really simple and something a lot of people do already.

Comment: It doesn't start at zero. It asks SQL what date is it and SQL returns the amount of peole already registered and the app populates the fields - with 0 if no session has been started before on the current date. It silently updates every couple of minutes if any counters have changed.
I don't see how this is over-complicated. It makes everything a lot simpler for everyone when the machines handle everything on their own without the risk of human error.
Also, how do you consider it simple "what others do" when that apparently does not account for midnight or not? :)

Comment: We've gone way off topic now by the way, haha. But I got what I came for nonetheless. There is no plausible way we'll ever open before 9 am or try to register entries after 9 am, so subtracting 9 hours cannot in any situation yield the wrong date. It's only possible if the clock on the iPhone is way off in which case it'll be wrong no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the cutoff is 9am, all you need to do is create an `NSDate` that's 9 hours earlier than the actual time.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-(9 * 3600)];
```

That way every day begins and ends at 9am.

Comment: This seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: Never ever subtract the number of seconds. This is so easy to break on daylight savings. Always use `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: Can you elaborate, @Sulthan? And Daylight savings hardly shift the clock nine hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interval to specific date like

```
[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```